# Datepicker and Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datepicker

Im trying to implement the datepicker.js with my laravel project. I downloaded the css/js and placed them in my assets and called them in the app template. Then I used my Js to call the date-picker on my form using the correct id but nothing is coming up and no errors either. Here is what I have:

**App:**

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/gin_add.css">

    <title>Elephant Gin</title>

</head>
<body>





@yield('main')


<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/gin_add.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form-Field:**

```
{!! Form::text('date', null, array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control datepicker','placeholder' => 'Pick the date this task should be completed', 'id' => 'calendar')) !!}
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('#calender').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    forceParse: false
});
```

Comment: When are you calling the `datepicker` function? on document ready? And also do you have any errors in console?

Comment: on document ready, and there were no errors.

Comment: Have you inspected the document itself for possible caching issues from the server?

Comment: Yea I watched the network to be sure the datepicker css/js loaded. No issues there. are there alternatives to the bootstrap datepicker? maybe something native to laravel?

Comment: Laravel doesn't support datepickers natively

Comment: When i reloaded the page and opened the console the date picker worked. However if i refreshed the page with the console open, nothing happens???  What is this about?

Comment: Why are you importing the javascript library two times?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking around google about Laravel and bootstrap-datepicker and found [this link](http://laravel.io/forum/09-11-2014-using-bootstrap-datepicker-in-laravel-4-form). One of the answer was:

> Just Curious.
>
> Did you have jQuery installed before your bootstrap-datepicker.js? Looks like jQuery is a dependency of this bootstrap-datepicker.js
>
> See: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

But it doesn't seem to be your case since you wrote

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/gin_add.js"></script>
```

but, in my opinion, it may still be a conflict with an existing JQuery datepicker... So as you can read from the [official documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#no-conflict-mode)  you can set your datepicker in `No conflict mode` by adding

```
var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict(); // return $.fn.datepicker to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;                 // give $().bootstrapDP the bootstrap-datepicker functionality
```